# What is the proper way to call this int Java request int

Tags: java

I cannot seem to get this and yet i know it's something simple. `getIntHeader` doesn't work right, as it only returns -1. It's driving me mad, so i know fresh eyes will help my over the mental block.

Here is the line:

```
this.price = request.getIntHeader("price");
```

all suggestions are welcome
thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need to give us a lot more information to answer this.

Comment: Ok sorry, i just want the price to enter into the database page and come out the same. the problem is on this page and on this line. I'm basically looking for alternatives to this line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well per Java EE documentation -1 means that the header with the name you specified does not exist in the request.

So...

1. Check the name.
2. Look at the request in debugger or from browser or wireshark and see what headers it has.
3. Decide what to do with missing header, or whether you are just looking for the wrong one.

The name "price" doesn't look very conventional as the name of an http header.
And so you may be looking for something in a header that is actually delivered in another way, e.g. query parameter, form field, etc.

If your client is not sending a header, you can't receive and process it.

Java EE Doc I read was silent about what happens when the header exists but the value is not an integer, as a price often would not be. I would expect it might throw NumberFormatException in that case. But didn't try it, and it's conceivable it might eat the exception and return -1. I would bet it throws NumberFormatException, in that case.

Comment: See i knew this, but my brain has hit a wall. Thank you so much for your input, I now know where I am..